# Why is the area of an elemental ring with radius $r$ and width $dr$ is $2πr dr$?

Tags: electrostatics, geometry, approximations

As shown below the topic is to calculate Electric Potential due to a disk whose surface charge density is $ \sigma $.

[image]
To do this we considered an elemental ring with inner radius = $r$, outer radius = $r+dr$.

As shown in figure, the $ \sigma $ is $ \frac{Charge}{Area} = \frac{dq}{2πr dr } $ .

But why the area is $ 2πr dr $ ? Which is perimeter × width?

Why not the area $ = π[(Outer radius)²-(Inner Radius)²] =π [(r+dr)²-(r²)] = π[2πr dr + (dr)²] $

Does the very very small quantity $(dr)²$ gets ignored?

Comment: Essentially covered in [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847047/the-surface-area-of-a-ring-pirdr2-r2-or-2-pi-r-dr)

Comment: Yes, $dr^2$ can be ignored, so your method is also correct (though you have an extra factor of $\pi$ in the first term that shouldn't be there).

Comment: It's not just that it is small. $r dr$ is small (infinitesimal), but $(dr)^2$ is infinitesimally smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it works to think of it as the $(dr)^2$ term getting ignored because it's so much smaller than the $dr$ term.

Alternatively, you can think of $r$ as being the radius midway between the inside and outside of the ring. The area of the ring is then

$$\pi\left(r+\frac{1}{2}dr\right)^2-\pi\left(r-\frac{1}{2}dr\right)^2=2\pi r dr\ \ ,$$

without needing to ignore a term containing $(dr)^2$.